# How to display an asterisk in an arbitrary font?

Tags: formatting

I have a string `"abc*"`. How can I display this in an arbitrary font? The `*` character is usually interpreted as an operator and it is not shown in the font set with `Style`.

I am looking for a solution that is usable in `Text` in `Graphics` as well as `PlotLabel`, `FrameLabels`, etc.

[image]